# Evaluate the definite integral using the rule of substitution.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

$\int_0^1 \sqrt[3] {1+7x}\; dx $

I have let u = 1+7x and so dx = $\frac 17$du.
Then I did when x=0, u=1 and when x=1, u=2. So the integral I am now trying to solve is

$\frac 17\int_1^2 \sqrt[3] {u}\; du $

When I do this I get that the integral of $\sqrt[3] {u}$ is $\frac{3u^\frac43}{4}  $.

When I solve for the final value I get $\frac{6\sqrt[3] {2}-3}{28} $ but the answer is suppose to be $\frac {45}{28}$, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your upper limit of integration is incorrect. When $x = 1, u = 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x=0$, $u=1$.  When $x=1$, $u=8$, not $2$.  Your upper limit of integration is wrong.